# Unable to use RabbitMQ RPC with ServiceStack distributed services.

Tags: servicestack, rabbitmq

For the life of me I have been unable to get RPC with RabbitMQ working with temp replyto queues. Below is a simple example derived from [this test](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/tests/ServiceStack.Server.Tests/Messaging/MqServerIntroTests.cs#L153). I see bunch of exceptions in my output window and the dlq fills up, but the message is never acknowledged.

```
namespace ConsoleApplication4
{
   class Program
   {
       public static IMessageService CreateMqServer(int retryCount = 1)
       {
           return new RabbitMqServer { RetryCount = retryCount };
       }

       static void Main(string[] args)
       {

           using (var mqServer = CreateMqServer())
           {
               mqServer.RegisterHandler<HelloIntro>(m =>
                   new HelloIntroResponse { Result = "Hello, {0}!".Fmt(m.GetBody().Name) });
               mqServer.Start();
           }

           Console.WriteLine("ConsoleAppplication4");
           Console.ReadKey();
       }
   }
}



namespace ConsoleApplication5
{
   class Program
   {
       public static IMessageService CreateMqServer(int retryCount = 1)
       {
           return new RabbitMqServer { RetryCount = retryCount };
       }

       static void Main(string[] args)
       {
           using (var mqServer = CreateMqServer())
           {
               using (var mqClient = mqServer.CreateMessageQueueClient())
               {
                   var replyToMq = mqClient.GetTempQueueName();
                   mqClient.Publish(new Message<HelloIntro>(new HelloIntro { Name = "World" })
                   {
                       ReplyTo = replyToMq
                   });

                   IMessage<HelloIntroResponse> responseMsg = mqClient.Get<HelloIntroResponse>(replyToMq);
                   mqClient.Ack(responseMsg);

               }
           }

           Console.WriteLine("ConsoleAppplication5");
           Console.ReadKey();
       }
   }
}
```

First exception

```
  RabbitMQ.Client.Exceptions.OperationInterruptedException occurred
    _HResult=-2146233088
    _message=The AMQP operation was interrupted: AMQP close-reason, initiated by Peer, code=405, text="RESOURCE_LOCKED - cannot obtain exclusive access to locked queue 'mq:tmp:10dd20804ee546d6bf5a3512f66143ec' in vhost '/'", classId=50, methodId=20, cause=
    HResult=-2146233088
    IsTransient=false
    Message=The AMQP operation was interrupted: AMQP close-reason, initiated by Peer, code=405, text="RESOURCE_LOCKED - cannot obtain exclusive access to locked queue 'mq:tmp:10dd20804ee546d6bf5a3512f66143ec' in vhost '/'", classId=50, methodId=20, cause=
    Source=RabbitMQ.Client
    StackTrace:
         at RabbitMQ.Client.Impl.SimpleBlockingRpcContinuation.GetReply()
         at RabbitMQ.Client.Impl.ModelBase.ModelRpc(MethodBase method, ContentHeaderBase header, Byte[] body)
         at RabbitMQ.Client.Framing.Impl.v0_9_1.Model._Private_QueueBind(String queue, String exchange, String routingKey, Boolean nowait, IDictionary`2 arguments)
         at RabbitMQ.Client.Impl.ModelBase.QueueBind(String queue, String exchange, String routingKey, IDictionary`2 arguments)
         at RabbitMQ.Client.Impl.ModelBase.QueueBind(String queue, String exchange, String routingKey)
         at ServiceStack.RabbitMq.RabbitMqExtensions.RegisterQueue(IModel channel, String queueName)
         at ServiceStack.RabbitMq.RabbitMqExtensions.RegisterQueueByName(IModel channel, String queueName)
         at ServiceStack.RabbitMq.RabbitMqProducer.PublishMessage(String exchange, String routingKey, IBasicProperties basicProperties, Byte[] body)
    InnerException:
```

followed by this one

```
  System.Threading.ThreadInterruptedException occurred
    _HResult=-2146233063
    _message=Thread was interrupted from a waiting state.
    HResult=-2146233063
    IsTransient=true
    Message=Thread was interrupted from a waiting state.
    Source=mscorlib
    StackTrace:
         at System.Threading.Monitor.ObjWait(Boolean exitContext, Int32 millisecondsTimeout, Object obj)
         at System.Threading.Monitor.Wait(Object obj, Int32 millisecondsTimeout, Boolean exitContext)
    InnerException:
```

Then it repeat for a number of times and hangs. This particular [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26063019) seems to suggest that they were able to achieve some sort of success with ServerStack and RabbitMQ RPC, but before I start changing my code I'd like to know the reason that my code doesn't work.

Thank you,
Stephen

Comment: If you declare exclusive queues, then those queues can't be accessed from other AMQP channels.

Comment: This issue has been resolved, and now everything is working perfectly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was an issue with redeclaring an exclusive queue which is no longer being done [in this commit](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/commit/5ddf12ba161a1a0b5ca480787c4fefbef9080098).

There's also a [new RabbitMqTest project](https://github.com/ServiceStack/Test/tree/master/src/RabbitMqTest) showcasing a simple working Client/Server example communicating via 2 independent Console Applications.

This change is available from v4.0.34+ that's [now on MyGet](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/MyGet).

The `ServiceStack.RabbitMq` package `RabbitMq.Client` NuGet dependency has also been upgraded to v3.4.0.

Answer (score 2):

When your client call GetTempQueueName(), it creates an exclusive queue, which cannot be accessed from another connection (i.e. your server).

Therefore I created my own simple mq-client which does not use servicestack's mq client and only depends on rabbitmq's .net-library:

```
    public class MqClient : IDisposable
    {
        ConnectionFactory factory = new ConnectionFactory()
        {
            HostName = "192.168.97.201",
            UserName = "guest",
            Password = "guest",
            //VirtualHost = "test",
            Port = AmqpTcpEndpoint.UseDefaultPort,
        };

        private IConnection connection;
        private string exchangeName;

        public MqClient(string defaultExchange)
        {
            this.exchangeName = defaultExchange;
            this.connection = factory.CreateConnection();
        }

        public TResponse RpcCall<TResponse>(IReturn<TResponse> reqDto, string exchange = null)
        {
            using (var channel = connection.CreateModel())
            {
                string inq_queue_name = string.Format("mq:{0}.inq", reqDto.GetType().Name);

                string responseQueueName = channel.QueueDeclare("",false,false,true,null).QueueName;
                //string responseQueueName = channel.QueueDeclare().QueueName;

                var props = channel.CreateBasicProperties();
                props.ReplyTo = responseQueueName;

                var message = ServiceStack.Text.JsonSerializer.SerializeToString(reqDto);

                channel.BasicPublish(exchange ?? this.exchangeName, inq_queue_name, props, UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message));

                var consumer = new QueueingBasicConsumer(channel);
                channel.BasicConsume(responseQueueName, true, consumer);


                var ea = (BasicDeliverEventArgs)consumer.Queue.Dequeue();
                //channel.BasicAck(ea.DeliveryTag, false);

                string response = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ea.Body);
                string responseType = ea.BasicProperties.Type;
                Console.WriteLine(" [x] New Message of Type '{1}' Received:{2}{0}", response, responseType, Environment.NewLine);

                return ServiceStack.Text.JsonSerializer.DeserializeFromString<TResponse>(response);

            }
        }

        ~MqClient()
        {
            this.Dispose();
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            if (connection != null)
            {
                this.connection.Dispose();
                this.connection = null;
            }
        }

    }
```

It can be used like that:

```
using (var mqClient = new MqClient("mx.servicestack"))
{
    var pingResponse = mqClient.RpcCall<PingResponse>(new Ping { });
}
```

**Important**: You've got to use servicestack version 4.0.32+.